# How can I tell if a package on npm will work with angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

By working I mean workin seamlessly where angular will not complain if I follow its "rules", like not manipulating the dom directly

Comment: You could setup a custom linter to check for any of usage of `document` based dom manipulators.

Comment: What package do you want to use?

Comment: @varunagarwal That is actually a pretty smart way to do it, I will give it a try, but I think some packages like chart js will fail, even though I use only the 2d context.

Comment: @SmokeyDawson I'm asking it for general purposes, since I like to map all my packages on the beginning of my projects

Comment: Yeah you can isolate your lint checks to work only with non-vendor code if that helps.